# Creating maps with tile URL using GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, tiles

I am new to GeoServer, and I plan to create a proprietary map with tile URL.

Will it possible to get the URL like this (http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png)
 from GeoServer?

How do I create the maps (If possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to get an URL like that, to know how [this link](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/webadmin/tilecache/index.html) is a good point to start.

Comment: Can you expand this question, and provide some more details? Links tend to rot, and if you provide more details, it will be more helpful in the long term